# Como mostrar a soma dos valores de uma Coluna usando PHP e SQL?

Tags: php

Quero mostrar a soma dos valores que estão na COLUNA `preco` da TABELA `contact_form_info` na parte do código onde está escrito `echo "<h1>&nbsp; Total Faturamento: R$$row['sum(preco)'].</h1>";`

```
<?php

include('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM contact_form_info";
$sqldata =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting');

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Whatsapp</th> <th>Preço</th></tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr><td>";

        echo $row['id'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['nome'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['whatsapp'];
        echo "</td><td>R$";

        echo $row['preco'];
        echo "</td><td>";
        }

echo "</table><br>";

echo "<h1>&nbsp; Total Faturamento: R$$row['sum(preco)'].</h1>";

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe várias formas de fazer isso, umas delas é aproveitar o `while` da query e criar uma acumulador, que a cada iteração do `while` some o valor do preço.

```
<?php

include('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM contact_form_info";
$sqldata =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting');
$totalPreco = 0;

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Whatsapp</th> <th>Preço</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //Acumulador do preço, totalizador
        $totalPreco += $row['preco'];

        echo "<tr><td>";

        echo $row['id'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['nome'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['whatsapp'];
        echo "</td><td>R$";

        echo $row['preco'];
        echo "</td><td>";
    }

echo "</table><br>";

echo "<h1>&nbsp; Total Faturamento: R$ $totalPreco.</h1>";

?>
```

---

Você também pode optar por criar uma outra query que retorne apenas o totalizados, utilizando o `sum`:

```
<?php

include('connect-mysql.php');

$sqlget = "SELECT * FROM contact_form_info";
$sqldata =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting');

//Bsuca o total dos preços utilizando o SUM do SQL
$sqlgetTotal = "SELECT SUM(preco) as total_preco FROM contact_form_info";
$sqldataTotal =  mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlgetTotal) or die('error getting');
$rowTotal = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldataTotal, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$totalPreco = $rowTotal['total_preco'];

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Nome</th> <th>Whatsapp</th> <th>Preço</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //Acumulador do preço, totalizador
        $totalPreco += $row['preco'];

        echo "<tr><td>";

        echo $row['id'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['nome'];
        echo "</td><td>";

        echo $row['whatsapp'];
        echo "</td><td>R$";

        echo $row['preco'];
        echo "</td><td>";
    }

echo "</table><br>";

echo "<h1>&nbsp; Total Faturamento: R$ $totalPreco.</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente!!! obrigado.

Comment: Ótimo! De nada! :D